# How to send the value of a dropdownlist along with the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that displays user names with groups they are part of. 
In case i switch the group of a user, how can i send bot the user and the new group to the controller ?

**View** :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>user ID</td>
        <td>user group</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.UserName</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("grup", new SelectList(ViewBag.GroupList, "ID", "UserGroupName"), item.UserGroupName)</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Save","EditUserGroup", UserInGroup)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Viewbag.GroupList is a list of {ID, GroupName}

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult EditUserGroup(UserInGroup userInGroup, string grup)
{
}
```

How can i send the value of the selected group and the user with all the details ?

**Edit**

I changed the Model to :

```
public class UserInGroupModel
{
    public IList<UserInGroup> userInGroupList { get; set; } 

    public int GroupId { get; set; }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult UserGroup()
    {
        IUserGroupService userGroupService = new UserGroupService();   

        ViewBag.GroupList = userGroupService.GetEntities();

        var lista = userInGroupService.GetEntities();

        UserInGroupModel userInGroupModel = new UserInGroupModel();
        userInGroupModel.userInGroupList = lista;

        return View(userInGroupModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUserGroup", "Admin"))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>user ID</td>
        <td>user group</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.userInGroupList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.UserName</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GroupId, new SelectList(ViewBag.GroupList, "ID", "UserGroupName"))</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

}

I still cannot send the value of the UserInGroup. I can get the GroupId in the groupId parameter of the controller but, the UserInModel entity is not passed. Can you help me ?

Comment: Create a ViewModel. Create a List Variable in ViewModel and send the ViewModel to the View

Answer (score 1):

use dropdownlistfor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.grup, new SelectList(ViewBag.GroupList, "ID"...
```

add a variable to your model for the selected item (grup in this case)